# Python PIP install error - textgenrnn

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to install textgenrnn.
I am somewhat new to python so I really don't understand these errors.
Any help would be excellent!
Thanks!

```
"c:\users\noah mirosch\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;
__file__='C:\\Users\\NOAHMI~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-l0csgm7x\\scikit-learn\\setup.py';
f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);
code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');
f.close();
exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" 
install --record C:\Users\NOAHMI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-ntkjc8ow\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" 
failed with error code 1 
in C:\Users\NOAHMI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-l0csgm7x\scikit-learn\
```

Comment: I need some more information. Can you edit your question to post with your code? How about reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Comment: Please make sure to have a look at the docs- [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I'm just using Pip install textgenrnn. It downloads successfully. I don't even know what this error might mean to affix more information on to the question.